# linq to object - Method not found

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq, exception

I am trying to use a simple LINQ to Objects query.

When I try to run my application I get the message:

```
System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled
  Message="An error occurred creating the form. See Exception.InnerException for details.  The error is: Method not found: 'Void sharatTashlumimWS.paymentDetailsManager.set_ReleaseDate(System.DateTime)'."
  Source="WindowsApplication1"
  StackTrace:
       at WindowsApplication1.My.MyProject.MyForms.Create__Instance__[T](T Instance) in 17d14f5c-a337-4978-8281-53493378c1071.vb:line 190
       at WindowsApplication1.My.MyProject.MyForms.get_Form1()
       at WindowsApplication1.My.MyApplication.OnCreateMainForm() in C:\MmiSources\Ksafim\APPLICATIONS\TashlumZikuy\Tashlumim\sharatTashlumimWS\WindowsApplication1\My Project\Application.Designer.vb:line 35
       at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun()
       at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.DoApplicationModel()
       at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run(String[] commandLine)
       at WindowsApplication1.My.MyApplication.Main(String[] Args) in 17d14f5c-a337-4978-8281-53493378c1071.vb:line 81
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException: System.MissingMethodException
       Message="Method not found: 'Void sharatTashlumimWS.paymentDetailsManager.set_ReleaseDate(System.DateTime)'."
       Source="WindowsApplication1"
       StackTrace:
            at WindowsApplication1.Form1..ctor()
       InnerException:
```

If I put this code in an ASP application it's run good.

My linq statement is:

```
Dim query = From m In movies Select m
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at the InnerException

```
InnerException: System.MissingMethodException
       Message="Method not found: 'Void sharatTashlumimWS.paymentDetailsManager.set_ReleaseDate(System.DateTime)'."
       Source="WindowsApplication1"
       StackTrace:
            at WindowsApplication1.Form1..ctor()
       InnerException:
```

Comment: +1. Do you have `Option Strict On`? If not, turn it on: and then I suspect the compiler may identify the problem for you.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the exception given, it looks like it's never even getting to your query -- something is going wrong in setting up `Form1`, probably in constructing the table of movies.